# Как перевести все латинские буквы в верхний регистр?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, replace

Нужно перевести все латинские символы в строке в верхний регистр.
Такой код не работает:

```
"Siemens system corp.".replace(/([A-z])/g, "$1".toUpperCase())
```

Comment: откуда такой странный интервал в выражении?

Comment: Вы забыли использовать стрелочные функции, а в остальном Ваш код правилен :) `"Siemens system corp.".replace(/([A-z])/g, $1 => $1.toUpperCase())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Метод `.replace()` [принимает](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) вторым параметром функцию. В ней можно сделать именно то, что вы хотите:

```js
console.log(
  "АбВ Siemens system corp. эЮя".replace(/[a-z]+/g, function (match) {
    return match.toUpperCase()}
  )
);
```

Обратите внимание, что запоминать совпадение в регулярном выражении не требуется. Кроме того, нет смысла искать буквы, которые уже в верхнем регистре.
Ну и строку в том виде, в котором вы её привели, вообще можно обработать через `"Siemens system corp.".toUpperCase()`, это так, к слову.

А в [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Example:_Using_an_inline_function_that_modifies_the_matched_characters) даже написано, почему ваш способ не работает:

> Поскольку мы хотим провести дополнительные преобразования *результата*
>   сопоставления до того, как будет использована окончательная
>   подстановка, мы должны использовать функцию. Это заставляет нас
>   принудительно вычислить сопоставление перед использование метода
>   `toLowerCase()`. Если бы мы попытались использовать сопоставление без
>   функции, метод `toLowerCase()` не сработал бы:
>
> `var newString = propertyName.replace(/[A-Z]/g, '-' + '$&'.toLowerCase());`
>
> Происходит это потому, что
>   сначала часть `'$&'.toLowerCase()` вычисляется в строковый литерал
>   (результат по-прежнему равен `'$&'`), а только потом его символы
>   используются в качестве шаблона.

Comment: Можно немного улучшить производительность путем замены регулярного выражения на `[a-z]+`, так будет меньше вызовов функции-реплейсера.

Comment: @ReinRaus, вы правы, исправил код в ответе.